# How to define a class which contains a variable dimension vector and how to use this class?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I want to define a class, which contains the variable dimension vector, and I defined a constructor to initialize it.

Now the problem is how can I use it? I want to use another vector to contain multiple of this class object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class block {
public:
    long Nx,Ny;
    vector<long> S;
    block(long &nx, long &ny):Nx(nx),Ny(ny),S((nx+1)*(ny+1),0) {}
};

int main() {
    vector<block> B;
    B.push_back(B(2,2));   //I believe this is wrong, but how can I do this?
    B.push_back(B(1,2));
    for(int k=B.begin(); k<=B.end(); k++) {
        for(int i=B[k].S.begin();i<=B[k].S.end();i++) {
        cout<<B[k].S[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class block {
public:
    long Nx,Ny;
    vector<long> S;
    block(long nx, long ny):Nx(nx),Ny(ny),S((nx+1)*(ny+1),0) {}
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not necessary to use inference
};

int main() {
    vector<block> B;
    B.push_back(block(2,2));   //use block(2,2)
    for(int i=0;i<B[0].S.size();i++) {
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^the right way to traversal the vector
        cout<<B[0].S[i];
    }
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, change B to block and add index[0] seems won't work, and the error message is still the same.

Comment: @northfly this code works perfectly in my computer. Try copy the whole code to your IDE and compile?

Comment: Thanks, that works for me now, but I still got problem, the output is 000000049 for B[0] and 0000000 for B[1]

Comment: LOL...Then you will open a new question?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
B.push_back(block(2,2));

for(int bi = 0; bi < B.size(); bi++ )
{
    block & refBlock = B[bi];

    for( int i = 0; i < refBlock.S.size(); i++ ) {
        cout << refBlock.S[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

The outer loop runs through the vector `B`.  We grab a reference to one element of `B` so we don't have to keep writing `B[bi]`, then the inner loop outputs all the elements of `S` for that `block`.

If you only want the first element of the vector `B`, then you can forget about the outer loop, and either use `B[0]` in place of `refBlock`, or do this:

```
block & refBlock = B[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I want, but I still got problem

Comment: It really helps if you say *what* your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

```
B.push_back(block(2,2));   
for(vector<long>::iterator i=B[0].S.begin();i<=B[0].S.end();i++) {
    cout<<*i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class block {
public:
    long Nx,Ny;
    vector<long> S;
    block(long nx, long ny):Nx(nx),Ny(ny),S((nx+1)*(ny+1),0) {}
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not necessary to use inference
};

int main() {
    vector<block> B;
    B.push_back(block(2,2));   //use block(2,2)
    B.push_back(block(2,1));
    for (int k=0; k<=B.size(); k++) {
        block & refBlock = B[k];

        for(int i=0; i<=refBlock.S.size(); i++) {
            cout<<refBlock.S[i];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got this program run, but the results is strange, the output is like the follows:

```
00000000049
0000000
```

however, what I expect is:

```
000000000
000000
```